# Replace newlines for lines matching regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a file like:

```
72810 82:28:1
this is text
hello world

72810 82:28:12
some more text
hello wolrd again
```

I need to replace the newline characters in just the lines containing 72810*
But there's a catch: I have tried the following:

`sed 's/\n/ /g' myfile.txt`

But this doesn't work.

I have also tried:

`cat myfile.txt | perl -p -e 's/72810.*\n/72810 /g'`

But this doesn't save the full original text (72810 82:28:1  or 72810 82:28:12 in this case).

What do I need to do to end up with the file looking like:

```
72810 82:28:1 this is text
hello world

72810 82:28:12 some more text
hello world again
```

By the way, I'm using solaris.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Comment: I have already searched for this specific question to no avail. This question involves being able to replace the newline on only specific matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -ne 'if (m/72810/) {s/\n/ /; print} else { print }' input.txt
```

Or this even shorter version:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if m/72810/' input.txt
```

You can use `-i` option to edit that `input.txt` in place.

Answer (score 2):

It seems simplest just to substitute the newline on all the lines that contain the test string. Like this

```
perl -pe "s/\n/ / if /72810/" myfile.txt
```

**output**

```
72810 82:28:1 this is text
hello world

72810 82:28:12 some more text
hello wolrd again
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^72810/{N;s/\n/ /}' file
```